# Exchange 2007 Powershell SnapIns not registering under Windows 7/Visual Studio 2008SP1

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server-2007

I have a user management application that I've written that works great under XP but as part of our prep for moving up to Windows 7 I have been trying to get it to run under Windows 7 and my Exchange PSSnapIn is not playing nice. It always reports

> "No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 2."

But I can go run add-pssnapin in Powershell and verify that it is in the list with get-pssnapin. I'm sure the obvious answer is that it's not a version 2 PSSnapIn, but why can I run it at the command line and not inside of my runspace?

Comment: Any chance this is a 64-bit system?  If so, you may be trying to access the Exchange Server pssnapin from the wrong bitness.

Comment: On my XP box I'm using the 32 bit version and on my Windows 7 box I am using 64 bit. I installed the correct version of Exchange Management Tools on both boxes.

Comment: But I belive the Exchange Server pssnapin is only available for one of the two (32 or 64 bit).  I "believe" it supports only 64 bit which means the snapin won't be registed for the 32-bit PowerShell engine.  Check to see if your app is running as 32-bit - check TaskManager on Win7 x64 and if its name is appended with *32 it is running as 32 bit and would explain your problem.  If that is the case then see if you can compile your app to target x64.

Comment: BTW you can also test this by open both a 64-bit and 32-bit (x86) PowerShell prompt on the Win7 x64 system.  Run get-pssnapin on both to see bitness the Exchange Server snapin is registered under.

Comment: From the command line it works on both, and on Windows 7 I've tried to compile with Any CPU, x86 and x64 and the result is the same every time.